# Scrolling Add Class Over Value Only Once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I stumbled upon an issue with a menu that I want to open by adding a "Open" class when scrolled above certain value. The issue is that I want it to open only ONCE after that value so it appears for the user, and then is up to the user to open and close it by a toggle.

I used this method:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 1150) {
            jQuery(".menubar").addClass("open");

        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The issue is that after the 1150 value, it keeps poping up after every scroll within this value.
How do I make it stop and make this event happen only once?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Check if the class is already existing. Or use a variable if the class changes too easily:

```
var isOpened = false;

jQuery(function() {
    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

     // The original if statement, testing for `.hasClass()`
     // if (scroll >= 1150 && !$(".menubar").hasClass()) {

        if (scroll >= 1150 && !isOpened) {
            isOpened = true;
            jQuery(".menubar").addClass("open");

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't do it like that, because the user may toggle the "open" class by manually closing it. In that case the class will not be there and it will pop up again with a scroll.

Comment: Then create another variable, like `userClosed` and check this too. @LeonVFX

Comment: @NickBull Just wanted to know about concept, since `isOpened` is by default `false` so how this statement will be true `if (scroll >= 1150 && isOpened) {...}` ?

Comment: @Mr.Developer Excellent spot! Forgot the `!`

Comment: @NickBull Now Understood the logic +10

Answer (score 0):

You can set a flag and then just check against that flag.

```
jQuery(function() {
    var menuBarOpenedOnce = 0;

    //caches a jQuery object containing the header element
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 1150 && menuBarOpenedOnce === 0) {
            jQuery(".menubar").addClass("open");
            menuBarOpenedOnce = 1;
        }
    });
});
```